# Why doesn't scanf read the value correctly?

Tags: c, unix, compiler-construction, printf, scanf

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ERROR 0
#define MAX_INPUT_LINE 80
#define print(x) {fputs(x,stdout);}
#define SUCCESS 1

int main (long argc, char *argv[])
{
   int mode;
   printf("1 for hexidecimal or 2 for binary");
   scanf("%d", mode);

   printf("\n\n\nThe value of mode is %d\n", mode);
   return 0;
}
```

When I enter **2** for binary, I get this:

```
The value of mode is 2665564
```

Obviously I should get 2, what am I doing wrong?? Is it my compiler, is it bevcause I am using Cygwin? Why is mode not 2??

Comment: What you do wrong is ignoring your compiler warning messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is C, not Java. When you use a function like `scanf (...)` since you cannot pass variables by reference, you are expected to pass a pointer to the variable that will hold the value.

Use the following instead:

```
scanf ("%d", &mode);
```

The use of (&) will pass the address-of mode, instead of implicitly casting mode to an `(int *)`.

You are actually quite lucky in this example that this did not cause your program to crash. If mode had a value of 0 and was cast to a pointer in order to satisfy this function, you could well wind up dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 7):

your scanf is wrong.  should be:

```
scanf("%d", &mode);
```

The `&` tells the compiler to send `scanf` a *pointer* to `mode` (i.e. its address) and not the actual value of `mode`.  That way `scanf` can put update `mode` with the new scanned value.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `scanf` wrong. For things like integer values, floating point values or characters, you need to provide a *pointer* to the variable to be filled. That's done most easily with the address-of operator `&`, like

```
scanf("%d", &mode);
```

The `scanf` family of functions also needs a pointer when reading a string, but since string already *are* pointers (or arrays which decays to pointers) you don't need the address-of operator for strings.

I suggest you read [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), as it contains a table showing what argument the different formatting codes expect.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of `scanf` is wrong, it expects a **pointer** to an `int` since the format is `%d`.

```
scanf("%d", &mode);
//          ^
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` is accepting pointers and then trying to put the value int the location the pointer is pointing at, meaning you can't send `mode` you need to send `&mode`. sending `mode` will cause Undefined Behavior.

do

```
scanf ("%d", &mode);
```

your full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ERROR 0
#define MAX_INPUT_LINE 80
#define print(x) {fputs(x,stdout);}
#define SUCCESS 1

int main (long argc, char *argv[])
{
   int mode;
   printf("1 for hexidecimal or 2 for binary");
   scanf("%d", &mode);

   printf("\n\n\nThe value of mode is %d\n", mode);
   return 0;
}
```

i would also state the if you want to print a number in hex mode use the `%x`:

```
printf("%x", mode);
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf`'s additional parameters is a address. Reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

By the way, the additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the format string.

So just change the 3rd line in `main()` to:

```
scanf("%d", &mode);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky enough for your program not to crash with a memory fault. As `mode` is not initialized, its value is undefined so you are storing an integer at a random address.

Later, you print that address in decimal.

This should "work" (if accepted by the compiler):

```
printf("%d\n",*mode);
```

or

```
printf("%d\n",*(int*)mode);
```

To clarify, I obviously do not recommend to dereference an uninitialized pointer. I'm just trying to explain why the program didn't crash and show how to get the entered value with keeping the bogus scanf as is (unlike all other replies which rightly fix the root cause). On a 32 bit environment, an `int` and a pointer are both stored in 4 bytes so are indistinguishable by the CPU. Of course the compiler should at least output a warning with such bogus code.

Comment: I don't think dereferencing uninitialized pointer is a good tip. For anyone. And since it's not even a pointer, it is so much worse idea.

Comment: @NathanFellman mode value doesn't change, it is used as the address where to store the integer.

Answer (score 1):

the scanf prototype is int scanf(const char *format, ...); hence use '&' to send the address...

Comment: This does not actually explain why you need to use the address of operator. Plenty of functions use `...` (variable-length argument lists) that do not require/expect pointers. The reason `scanf` needs a pointer is because it uses the variable-length arguments to store the parsed values.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. i was in hurry and wanted to tell to use address of operator in the code but didn't frame my answer in a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
scanf("%d", &mode);
```

you have missed the `&` symbol in your code.